# Specify any intermediate/intervening directory

Tags: git, git-add

When I want to `git add` a file, it's often in a subdirectory.

Imagine I have this set of changed files and I want to `git add some_file.txt`:

```
foo/bar/some_file.txt
foo/bar/other_file.txt
foo/baz/third_file.txt
```

I've seen somewhere that there is a way to say:

```
git add foo/{any intermediate directory}/some_file.txt
```

I thought it involved `foo/../some_file.txt` but it can't be that because that means "parent directory"

What was it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `**` to specify "any directory":

```
$ git add foo/**/some_file.txt
```

Comment: `shopt -s globstar` By default it's off.